# how to use dynamic routing in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router

this is my json object ,i'm trying to access jackets in my url

```
{
  "_id": "6316f215fd9c107baa1bc160" 
  "type": "Jackets",
}
```

this is my router component to get product by id

```
 {
    path: "/product/:id",
  },
```

if i want to get my product information by id

```
 <router-link :to="`/product/${product._id}`">
                  <div
                    class="bg-image hover-zoom ripple"
                    data-mdb-ripple-color="light"
                  >
                    <img
                      src="../../assets/pexels-baskin-creative-studios-1766838.jpg"
                      class="card-img-top"
                    />

                  </div>
                </router-link>
```

this is my url

```
http://localhost:8082/product/6316f215fd9c107baa1bc160
```

i get jackets in my template after clicking the router-link

```
{{product.type}}
```

how can i get add jackets in my url to something like this

```
http://localhost:8082/product/jackets
```

and still display the json details in my template component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You want to slightly change the current route path without refreshing/reloading the page. If Yes, You can achieve that by using [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) API.

```
history.replaceState({}, '', this.$route.path + '/' + <your product name>)
```

Comment: I'm trying to bind the title property to my url and display the product details under the url....just like get an element by id

Comment: @jibzy Yes I understood that. Did you tried the solution I provided ?

Comment: If I may ask where do I place this

Comment: In your component method, before or after making an API call.

Comment: this what i get in my url....http://localhost:8082/blog/63246b5147953ee6907f7337/title , this how i placed it in my mounted hook     history.replaceState({}, '', this.$route.path + '/' + "title" )    .....how can i make it dynamic to get jackets thank you

Comment: @jibzy You are passing `"title"` as a string. It should be a variable like `product.type`. history.replaceState({}, '', this.$route.path + '/' + this.product.type )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248167/discussion-between-jibzy-and-rohit-jindal).